# How to return custom response on failing validation in Struts 2

Tags: java, json, configuration, struts2, struts-validation

Let me explain what I'm doing first :

I'm writing an API, which returns JSON on success or failure and there's a `status` variable within the returned JSON, which lets the end-user know where it's a `success` or `failure`.

Now, if an API expects to submit some parameters, then if that parameter is a double & the submitted value is a string, then I have to return JSON with `status` false and an error message in an `errorlist`.

By-default the interceptors in between, failing to set the `String` to some `Number` returns `Action.INPUT` result without executing the action method.

I tried annotating the method with `@SkipValidation` but still the method code doesn't execute and it returns `INPUT` straight away from the interceptor (I guess).

I've by default defined the status to be `true` then in the action method, depending on the conditions, I set it false if required, but since now the action is never executed, the JSON response returned, is having status to be true and the `errorlist` is empty (since the action didn't executed, which used to add error to the list).

**Action Code:**

```
 @SkipValidation
    public String saveFund() {
          //some code which is never executed when Double variable is a string
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**Interceptor stack being used:**

```xml
<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="nlogin" class="interceptors.AdminInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="nlogin"/>
        <!--<interceptor-ref name="store">-->
        <!--<param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>-->
        <!--</interceptor-ref>-->
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
```

Comment: Post some code at least.

Comment: @RomanC added action & interceptor stack being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the action is not executed means that you have validation errors. The [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html) returns `Action.INPUT` result in this case when the validate method complete if any.

So, you want to return a JSON in this circumstances. To return JSON you should create a result with a name `"input"` and type `"json"` and add it to the action configuration.

When the validation completed, that you might use a `validate()` method to customize the result, the input result will be executed and if it's JSON type then JSON response will be returned.

Comment: I've already added `SkipValidation` annotation and hence, the action should execute. Secondly, you mean to say that `validate()` is executed at all costs, right ? So, I can fill json fields in `validate()` ?

Comment: "`validate()` is executed at all cost", if none other interceptor (either standard or of your) has thrown an exception (or returned a result) before the Validation Interceptor.

Comment: @RomanC yep was answering its comment, not your answer... the sentence "is executed AT ALL COST" needed to be clarified